# Downloading kaggle files in R without getting the 'Permission denied' error

Tags: r, download, kaggle

I am trying to download Kaggle data files directly in R:

```
download.file("http://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting/download/train.csv.zip", "/train.csv.zip")
Error in download.file("http://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting/download/train.csv.zip",  : 
  cannot open destfile '/train.csv.zip', reason 'Permission denied'
```

Any known walk arounds?

Answer (score 3):

Your `destfile` is incorrect.  `destfile` is the destination for the downloaded file (on your computer).  I usually use a `tempfile` to create a temporary file as a destination for the download, and then `unlink` it later.

```
tmp <- tempfile()
url <- "http://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-store-sales-forecasting/download/train.csv.zip"
download.file(url, destfile = tmp)
```

Then check `list.files('tmp')` (depending on where `tmp` is on your computer), `unzip` it, read it, and use `unlink(tmp)` to dump it once you've read it into R.

Comment: It might be wrong but this can't be the file, the file is over 1 MB

Comment: It's because I don't have a kaggle account so I can't get past the login page.  Did you try it for yourself?

Comment: I do but I am guessing that it doesn't work without cookies, is there a way to download a file with cookies (similar to wget -x --load-cookies in bash  code)?